# Using a Regular Expression Validator for numbers in a textbox

Tags: asp.net

How can I use a Regular Expression Validator to ensure that only a number like 3.00 is entered into a text box?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `CompareValidator` with `type="Double"` to allow numbers only.

Using the `RegularExpressionValidator` you could use this `ValidationExpression`: `\d+\.\d{2}` (One or more digits, a decimal point, two digits.)

I always use this [nice little tool](http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html) to compose regular expressions.

Does this answer your question or do you need help on how to use the `RegularExpressionValidator` control in general?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify those cases like 123, 123., 123.12, and .23, the following may be used:

```
ValidationExpression="(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+\.)|(\.\d+)|(\d+)"
```