# How to avoid input space and special character

Tags: c#, devexpress, dom-events, asp.net-3.5

I work on asp.net C#  Window application. in **AspxTextbox** I want to avoid space and arrow key and also special character. I want just user can input **number 0 to 9 and a to z character**.

Comment: Regular Expressions are your friend. Refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236063/how-to-check-in-textbox-to-enter-only-like-3-00-using-regular-expression-validato

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you use the following code:

```
      <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px">
        <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s, e) { 
if( 
      (e.htmlEvent.keyCode &gt;= 48 &amp;&amp; e.htmlEvent.keyCode &lt;= 57) ||
      (e.htmlEvent.keyCode &gt;= 97 &amp;&amp; e.htmlEvent.keyCode &lt;= 122) ) 

  {  }
  else { _aspxPreventEvent(e.htmlEvent); }
}"/>
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the DevExpress AspxTextbox allows you to specify some JavaScript to achieve this. If you're inclined to use the DexExpress controls to their fullest, consider the `ClientSideEvents` element. The following JavaScript attached to the KeyPress event will allow numbers only.

- 48 to 57 is to allow 0 through 9
- 97 to 122 are a through z (lowercase)
- [if you require more ASCII values to be allowed, refer to the chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)

```
<dxe:ASPxTextBox runat="server" EnableClientSideAPI="True" ID="foo"  
                 ClientInstanceName="bar">

  <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s, e) {
  if( 
      (e.htmlEvent.keyCode >= 48 && e.htmlEvent.keyCode <= 57) ||
      (e.htmlEvent.keyCode >= 97 && e.htmlEvent.keyCode <= 122) ) 

  { return true; }
  else {  return false;}

  }" />                                         
</dxe:ASPxTextBox>
```

Of course, modify as you see fit, and as you require. [More context at the DevExpress site](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q94010.aspx).

Comment: sorry..Next i will be more careful ,will you plz help me .How to solve this issue.thanks for reply.